# how to print /show result in table form that can be read python jupyterlab

Tags: python, machine-learning, show, jupyter-lab

I want to print epoch result in table form that can be read [image]

Comment: I took out the epoch tag since I don’t think your question carries any direct connection to January 1, 1970 at 00:00 UTC, the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 1):

```
model_history = model.fit(...)

loss = model_history.history['loss']
val_loss = model_history.history['val_loss']

plt.figure()
plt.plot(model_history.epoch, loss, 'r', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(model_history.epoch, val_loss, 'bo', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss Value')
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Gives nice graph of model loss and saves all data

Comment: I mean the output of printed text is not uniform    ann.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)

Comment: looks nice but what is loss and val_loss can you give me there equations

Comment: you are using sparse categorical cross entropy so its: [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MXNET/Multi-hot+Sparse+Categorical+Cross-entropy#:~:text=Categorical%20Cross%20Entropy-,Definition,only%20belong%20to%20one%20class.)